# Turning numbers into uppercase numbers with NSAttributedString/NSString and UILabel

Tags: ios, fonts, nsstring, uilabel, uppercase

I'm using a font here that has different looks for uppercase and lowercase numbers. This works perfectly in text editors, and Adobe's tools (by settings labels to uppercase only), and I figured this would work in UIKit as well by just running the string through the uppercaseString method, but it doesn't seem to actually turn the numbers into their uppercase versions.

So… How can I turn numbers into uppercase in UIKit? Can I?

Comment: Did you try `- (NSString *)uppercaseStringWithLocale:(NSLocale *)locale`?

Comment: I did try uppercaseStringWithLocale with both systemLocale, currentLocale, my own and en_US. Neither had any effect.

And yes, some fonts seem to have uppercase and lowercase numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This blog post](http://blog.amyworrall.com/post/46329875785/core-text-and-upper-case-numbers) may help.

Also note that while there [are quite a few different terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures) for these, in the world of typography they are more typically known as ***lining*** and ***old-style*** figures, not "uppercase and lowercase numbers"

Comment: Hi djangodude, we're looking for a font expert for our startup (en.youscribe.com). Are you interested in doing some work for us or know someone who can help us on these subject (as a contractor) ? If so, feel free to contact me : yann.robin (at) youscribe [.com]